# Codeigniter passing variable to URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a list of posts and an `edit` link for each. When clicking `edit` it goes to a page where I can edit the specific post I clicked on. For this I will have to pull from the db the id of the post.

Would this be the correct way to do it?

`<a href="<?php echo site_url("post/edit/$row->id"); ?>">Edit</a>`

`post` is my controller, `edit` is my function, and `$row->id` should pull the id of the post.

Comment: Hover the edit link of your question to know the answer! ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it seems correct to do

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("post/edit/".$row->id); ?>">Edit</a>
```

Just make sure that your action method (edit in this case) accepts an argument with the post id that you need to fetch.

Comment: how do we receive that value from url ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is the right way to do it, just like the edit link in SO...just make sure to validate the ID in your controller before processing

Answer (score 2):

PHP won't interpret $row->id correctly within your string. you need to concatenate it at the end, EG:  `site_url("post/edit/".$row->id)`

Comment: Sure? no, I haven't tested his code. Had errors previously when I tried to use objects within a string? Yes, I have.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct... Your code would throw an error

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("post/edit/{$row->id}"); ?>">Edit</a>
```